# Firebase Hosting Path Parameters in URL Not Working

Tags: firebase, url-rewriting, firebase-hosting

I need to serve dynamic content by using path parameters to fetch an `id` from the URL when hosting on firebase. For example:

> mydomain.com/apps/4480023

In this scenario, I'd like to extract `4480023` as the ID of the resource I'm looking for. I tried the following changes in the firebase.json file:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      },
      {
        "source": "/apps/**",
        "destination": "/apps.html"
      }
    ],
    "cleanUrls": true
  }
}
```

In which case, I can use a javascript function to retrieve the ID from the URL when the user browses to that resource. My problem is, this rewrite doesn't work and it directs the user to the index.html page and all the CSS/JS files end up not functioning correctly.

How can I modify this to enable this functionality?

Comment: can you share the code how to extract param after sorting the firebase.json

Comment: @Hanzala do you mean query param? Like: `website.com?user=2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rewrites are checked in order.  This means your first rewrite, which matches all requests, is always going to be served by index.html.

All you have to do is change the order of the rewrites to allow `/apps/**` to have a possibility of matching before `/**` captures everything else.

```
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "/apps/**",
    "destination": "/apps.html"
  },
  {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  }
]
```

Comment: Didn't think that would cause this issue. Thanks :)